# Scroll View on Header View of Table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am implementing a Table View with a short cut menu on header view of the tableview. the example i have is almost close to the screen shot below.

[image]

But i have implemented a simple header view on table view with menu, in this case the header view just have one set of menu and not scrollable vertically. but i would like to add the scrollable component so can accommodate more than just 8 icons.

here is a picture of what i have done

[image]

Any help advice will be great ! if some examples will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a UICollectionView in your tableViewHeader.

Comment: But how do you think i should implement the 2nd 3rd and 4th sections , also in header view or as table view sections in the table view.

Comment: It's fine in the header view. The collectionView can show multiple pages that are layout horizontally.

Comment: I Understood abt the 1st div of the headerview but before the actual tableview there are 4 sections. the real tableview starts only after the heading "POPULAR". before that there is a 2nd section with 3 columns in a single row and 2 columns&2 rows in 3rd section and 3rd section with 1 row with 2 columns & another with 4 columns. is it possible to add this many views in header, or are these modification of table view sections ? i'm self learned developer and it is 2 many to try by trial & error so if some one can help with little more deeper advice on the direction i should take, will be great